# Blocking requests on postfix (fail2ban)

Tags: postfix-mta, fail2ban

I see the same non smtp requests in my maillog and I can't figure out, what is missing so those requests can be blocked.

fail2ban is setup and I have configured a jail.local file. How can I block those 6 requests:

```
Feb 10  10:58:57    host    postfix/submission/smtpd[5167]: warning:    non-SMTP    command from    unknown[161.35.7.72]:   GET /system_api.php HTTP/1.1
Feb 10  10:58:57    host    postfix/submission/smtpd[5167]: warning:    non-SMTP    command from    unknown[161.35.7.72]:   GET /c/version.js   HTTP/1.1
Feb 10  10:58:58    host    postfix/submission/smtpd[5167]: warning:    non-SMTP    command from    unknown[161.35.7.72]:   GET /streaming/clients_live.php HTTP/1.1
Feb 10  10:58:58    host    postfix/submission/smtpd[5167]: warning:    non-SMTP    command from    unknown[161.35.7.72]:   GET /stalker_portal/c/version.js    HTTP/1.1
Feb 10  10:58:58    host    postfix/submission/smtpd[5167]: warning:    non-SMTP    command from    unknown[161.35.7.72]:   GET /client_area/   HTTP/1.1
Feb 10  10:58:59    host    postfix/submission/smtpd[5167]: warning:    non-SMTP    command from    unknown[161.35.7.72]:   GET /stalker_portal/c/  HTTP/1.1
```

The jail.local for postfix config is shown below:

```
[postfix]

# To use another modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
enabeld = true
mode    = more
port    = smtp,ssmtp,submission
logpath = %(postfix_log)s
backend = %(postfix_backend)s

bantime  = 1000
findtime  = 10000
maxretry = 3
maxmatches = %(maxretry)s
bantime.increment = true
bantime.rndtime = 1000
bantime.factor = 1
bantime.formula = ban.Time * (1<<(ban.Count if ban.Count<20 else 20)) * banFactor
bantime.multipliers = 1 2 4 8 16 32 64
bantime.overalljails = true
```

It looks like the postfix default rules are not blocking / banning those non-smtp requests. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the missing part was the "HOST" in the filter, so fail2ban knows which IP to ban.

the filter now looks like this:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^.*\[<HOST>].*system\_api
            ^.*\[<HOST>].*c\/version\.js
            ^.*\[<HOST>].*streaming\/clients
            ^.*\[<HOST>].*client\_area
            ^.*\[<HOST>].*stalker\_portal

datepattern = ^[^\[]*\[({DATE})
              {^LN-BEG}

ignoreregex =
```

Comment: A link to the any documentation that describes the format of the datepattern for fail2ban would be  very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try to define fail regex in your conf file for instance :

```
failregex = 161.35.7.72.*GET.*/system_api.php.*
```

For more output check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/773700/im-trying-to-catch-brute-force-against-xmlrpc-php-with-fail2ban)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old and hopefully resolved, but your rule is not enabled. (You've misspelled it as "enabeld".)